# Merging the detached entity in current hibernate session without reloading it from DB

Tags: hibernate

I need to know if there is a way to merge the detached entity in current hibernate session without reloading the entity from DB.

**Here is the scenario :**

I have a table CodeItem as given below

```
CodeItem
-------------------
Code      | varchar
CodeType  | varchar
Label     | varchar
```

The pk is a composite key comprising of columns `(Code, CodeType)` and there is no identity column.

The DB is SQLServer 2012 and the ORM is hibernate 4.

Hibernate L2 cache is implemented and it is working fine for all the entities except the CodeItem entity.

The CodeItem entity is cached whenever it is accessed for the first time but when the same entity is accessed it is not retrieved from cache but from DB, as identity column is not there.

For some restrictions I cannot change the table definition.
To overcome the performance issue I have implemented the spring cache mechanism, which is working fine.

The problem is that when I retrieve the CodeItem entity from spring cache region, I need to merge it in hibernate session as it is a detached entity.
For that I am using `session.merge`, which will reload the entity from DB.

Is there any way in which I can merge the detached CodeItem entity to hibernate session without making DB query?

I wish to have an interface like

```
session.merge(entity, reloadFromDBFlag)     //where reloadFromDBFlag is boolean
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not possible.

Hibernate would not be able to check what has changed in the object if it does not know its previous (persisted) state (thus it would not be able to generate the proper SQL when flushing the changes made by merging).

Comment: Thanks for your quick response.

In my case, entity will never change as it represent the read-only master data.

Comment: @SarafrazSayyad In that case, don't cascade entity lifecycle operations to that entity from other entities and use it as detached. However, I would use this as a temporary quick fix and would move to using L2 cache as soon as possible.

Comment: Is that still the case in 2023? It's an issue when working with custom DB calls that use provider specific syntax.